# How to get date range with frappe.db.get_list()?

Tags: erp, frappe

I'm trying to get subscriptions ending in a given month using the [DB API documented here](https://frappe.io/docs/user/en/api/database).

I can get before a certain date with:

```
end_period = datetime.date(2020, 12, 31)
frappe.db.get_list('Subscription', filters={
    'current_invoice_end': ['<', end_period]
})
```

But how would I specify before `end_period` and after `start_period`?

When I tried

```
frappe.db.get_list('Subscription', filters={
    'current_invoice_end': ['<', end_period],
    'current_invoice_end': ['>', start_period]
})
```

It treated it as "OR" and listed things outside of the range.

*cross-posted at [discuss.erpnext.com](https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/how-to-use-a-date-range-with-db-api/62348)*

Answer (score 2):

You can quickly search for "between" in the erpnext src to check implementations. 
It has been the only reliable source for me.

```
"holiday_date": ["between", (self.start_date, self.end_date)],
```

The solution you posted wont work because Python wont allow two keys with the same name on the dict.

Another solution that will return a list could be

```
holidays = frappe.db.sql_list('''select holiday_date, rate from `tabHoliday`
        where
            parent=%(holiday_list)s
            and holiday_date >= %(start_date)s
            and holiday_date <= %(end_date)s''', {
                "holiday_list": holiday_list,
                "start_date": self.start_date,
                "end_date": self.end_date
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass filters as a list:

```
frappe.db.get_list('Subscription', filters=[
    ['current_invoice_end', '<', end_period],
    ['current_invoice_end', '>', start_period]
])
```

I would avoid using direct SQL for this!