# Date range for query (Frappe)

Tags: python, mysql, frappe

I want to create a filter for a frappe query that finds values which have a date between 2 other dates. Specifically, the Salary slip start_date and end_date should enclose the attendance_date.

```
doc_name = ##Some Salary Slip
document = frappe.get_doc('Salary Slip', doc_name)

leave_count = frappe.db.count('Attendance', filter={
    'employee': document.get('employee'),
    'status': 'Present',
    'late_entry': 1,
    'attendance_date': ['>=', document.get('start_date')],
    'attendance_date': ['<=', document.get('end_date')]})
```

Now this wont work as there are duplicate entries in the dictionary. So as per [1](https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/how-to-use-a-date-range-with-db-api/62348) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201849/how-to-get-date-range-with-frappe-db-get-list), I should be able to use lists as filters, but trying it like this

```
leave_count = frappe.db.count('Attendance', filters=[
             ['employee', '=', document.get('employee')],
             ['status', '=', 'Present'],
             ['late_entry', '=', 1],
             ['attendance_date', '>=', document.get('start_date')],
             ['attendance_date', '<=', document.get('end_date')]])
```

but it throws an error,

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

And a quick peek at the code explains that currently only diciontaries are supported with the for loop that expects keys and not lists, and `between` is not option as that operator is automatically converted to '=' and that doesn't work.

So how do I do this?

**Edit**: the easiest method currently is to use frappe.db.get_list and count the results in python. While this is inefficient, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run a raw SQL query using `frappe.db.sql` method.

```
result = frappe.db.sql("""
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tabAttendance`
WHERE
    employee=%(employee)s
    AND status= 'Present'
    AND late_entry= 1,
    attendance_date between %(start_date)s AND %(end_date)s
""", {
    'employee': document.get('employee')
    'start_date' : document.get('start_date')
    'end_date' : document.get('end_date')})
leave_count = result[0][0]
```